# What is this glassy black bulge on a keytar button chip?

Tags: identification, components, touch

I'm disassembling a non-functioning toy keytar. This is the chip behind a couple buttons, including an on/off button. What could the black, glassy bulge component be?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an on board IC chip bonded directly to the board with an epoxy blob protecting it. Common in low cost assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy!

Comment: Yep... In the biz we call this 'die bonding'